# Inputs not work in Ionic app on IOS emulator

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3

I build ionic app in xcode. It's launch in simulator (IPhone XS) without errors, but when I click on input, its not focused.

How i can solve this problem?

Debug output:

```
2018-10-10 15:06:36.086338+0300 TiH Mobile[32564:860565] ****** ERROR ******
2018-10-10 15:07:30.200169+0300 TiH Mobile[32564:860565] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/skhalimonov/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/50E14C60-CD7D-4020-944B-FED0F68CE15A/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

2018-10-10 15:07:30.201144+0300 TiH Mobile[32564:860565] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

2018-10-10 15:07:30.360117+0300 TiH Mobile[32564:860565] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7fdb27e18af0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000015bf120>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

2018-10-10 15:07:30.360312+0300 TiH Mobile[32564:860565] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7fdb27e18af0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000015bf120>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
```

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
   @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : browser 5.0.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (18 plugins total)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
```